# Maven - How to get/set properties of a specific profile in java?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

1. In case some profiles share the same properties, How do I define them once in the pom and in the settings.xml? (Is there any "profile inheritence"?)
2. How do I get from java in runtime all the properties that were defined in:

   1. pom.xml.
   2. settings.xml.
   3. command: mvn install -D environment.type=dev

Comment: Did you read: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html?

Comment: yes and also http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/pdf/mvnref-pdf.pdf